# NRZ-S with Python

Tags: python

I have this array, which is a digital signal (in theory):

```
array_nrz = [1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0]
```

I want to plot both the NRZ and NRZ-S encodings. How can I transform this array into an NRZ-S signal?

```
array_transformed_nrz_s = [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
```

Here are two illustrated examples.

[image: http://www.tpub.com/neets/book23/0060.GIF]

[image: http://www.itwissen.info/bilder/nrz-s-codierung.png]

Is there a package I could use?

From what I understand the signal changes only when it encounter a 0.

Comment: if you use engineer calculation, you should look at numpy or scipy

Comment: I searched and I didn't find an NRZ-S encoding implementation in both numpy or scipy

Comment: i found this `Non-Return-to-Zero Space
"One" is represented by no change in level
"Zero" is represented by change in level.` 
http://ckp.made-it.com/encodingschemes.html so the idea is always to compate `data[n]` with `data[n-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the second illustration is bogus and should not be considered.

Here is some code that works:

```
NRZ = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1]
NRZS = []

state = NRZ[0]
for bit in NRZ:
    state ^= bit ^ 1
    NRZS.append(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is using a function so it will be easy to execute it:

```
def nrzs(nrz):
    NRZS = []
    state = nrz[0]
    for bit in nrz:
        state ^= bit ^ 1
        NRZS.append(state)
    return NRZS
```

The console:

```
In [4]: nrzs([0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1])
Out[4]: [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```